# disabled textbox

Tags: asp.net

i m using one disabled textbox in my page .it is looking disabled in mozilla firefox but looking like a simple textbox in IE.what to do to give it a disabled look in IE also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of IE you are testing with, you can change the background colour of the textbox yourself using CSS:

`background-color: #999999`

Other than that, there isn't a whole lot you can do. Older versions of IE are a pain to work with, and form elements are notorious for lacking styling support.

Comment: It's a CSS property, so you can either put it in an external CSS file on a selector for your textbox, or you can inline it by adding a style attribute to your textbox — something like: <input type="text" style="background-color: #999999;">

Answer (score 0):

Usually disable behavior is the other way around; you can't override all the styling IE places on disabled HTML controls.  But you can in FireFox and other browsers.  If you need to give an appearance of not being disabled when actually being disabled, you should look at using a Label server control to display what you need.